# jpa select string found in where in caluse

Tags: jpa

I have a list of strings and i need to search them in my table then construct new class contain key as on of my search strings and value as my pojo if exist or null if not exist.

something like that :

```
Class MyMapper {

    private String identificationKey;
    private User user;
    // Getter and Setter

}
```

My Expected Query:

```
SELECT NEW MyMapper(identificationKey, u) From User u where u.identification IN :identificationKeys
```

i need to select every identificationKey in identificationKeys even not exist

Comment: Probably this could help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321916/jpa-criteriabuilder-how-to-use-in-comparison-operator
or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109412/in-clause-with-a-composite-primary-key-in-jpa-criteria

Comment: and what have you tried? and what is the problem?

Comment: The problem as i illustrated in my question, i need query can select every string found in list using after In clause